# UILabel resize in storyboard when I edit the text

Tags: ios, uilabel, uistoryboard

I have `UILabel` with a long sentence. And every time I edit the text in the `Storyboard`, like adding a word or whatever it resize and stretch outside its VC.  This is extremely annoying, how can I edit the text in the `Storyboard` while keeping the text inside the predefined size of the `UILabel` ?  I have Lines set to 0.

Comment: Have you added layout constraints? Are you editing direct in the label or in the info inspector?

Comment: Did you set some constraints for your UILabel?

Comment: @wain Have added constraints, I am editing the text in the Label, not Inspector

Comment: try it in the inspector

Comment: Great, thanks ! That worked